# How to evaluate the retrained multiple model files in stanford sentiment tool

Tags: stanford-nlp

I trained around 30,000 sentences using Stanford SentimentTraining class. At the end of training, around 50 model files got created(with the extension .ser.gz). But while evaluating  it is told to use this command:

```
java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.Evaluate -model edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz -treebank test.txt
```

My question is how can I use all the generated model files instead of sentiment.ser.gz?

Answer (score 2):

Intermediate models are saved with the format

```
<basename>-<version>-<score>.ser.gz
```

where `<basename>` is the basename of the model path you provide (minus extension), `<version>` is the index of this model in the sequence of saved models, and `<score>` is the exact node accuracy of this model.

You can pick whichever of these models you'd like by score, or just use the final output model (though of course the final model isn't guaranteed to be the best!).

Comment: Thanks Jon. By final model,you mean model.ser.gz right.

Comment: Yes, that's the model that's saved at the very end of training.